# Jupyter & Conda: how to set different working directories for different environments

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

i'm working on a fresh Anaconda3 installation. I want to create different environments for different projects. In each environment i want to use jupyter, so i'm installing it in each of them:

```
conda create --name test_env python=3.7
conda activate test_env
conda install jupyter
```

Inside this env, to point jupyter to the working directory i tried with:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

I opened the created file and edited original line with:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'path_to_test_env_working_dir'
```

The problem is that, for every env i create, the working directory is always the same. How can i solve this problem?

NOTE: if you know other ways to keep different projects safe and tidy, let me know. Thanks!